# php error when uploading at the same time

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, upload

I have a very simple upload function that receives data (a picture) form a $FILES - it works fine when uploading from times to times. However, if I increase the charge and send quickly a lot of files, it crashes (I don't even get error msg...)

Obviously, it's not a problem of uploading multiples files here - files may be uploaded by different users...

in the index.php, I have :

```
switch ($_POST['command']) {    
case "testWrite":
testWrite($_FILES['picture']);
break;
```

Then the function is:

```
function testWrite($data){
    $filename=....;
    if ($data['error']==0) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($data['tmp_name'], $filename)) {

        } else {

        };
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You might check and raise the `php.ini` settings for `max_file_uploads` and `memory_limit`.
The last setting is not so obvious but also affects file uploading.

Enable error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

In your else section you might dump the error:

```
else {
    echo 'File upload error: ' . $_FILES[0]['error'];
    // or maybe var_dump($_FILES); to see it all
}
```

Comment: I have checked the ['error'] and it's empty - what's weird is that when I send 10 files/sec (files with 1ko size), the ['tmp_name'] is even empty! (whereas normally that's the real tmp file name...)

Comment: I have tested with the var_dump. If I try to upload 10 files very quickly, the first 9 files fail and don't even return a var_dump !!! I have double checked with a sanity check, and I can normally see the var_dump of a $_FILE...

Comment: Hmm, tricky. Please check `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` - just to be sure, these values are set and are higher than the file size. Folder permissions (writeable) for tmp folder and target folder?

Comment: I have double checked with the hosting service - it's like 10mo and 20mo... compared to the 1ko of the file...

Comment: FYI - the hosting is site ground, and it's a shared hosted account. Not sure if it's related here

Comment: Maybe they have some kind of "upload throttling"? I think we discussed every possible error: ini-settings, correct folder names, permissions, error displaying. 1 thing left: "multipart encoding" set on the form?

Comment: not sure for the throttling... Yes it's a multipart encoding form (at least an object that looks like it in objective C...). Is there something particular I should be careful with in that case?

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` must be set on the form, but i guess it is, because single file upload works. I'm out of ideas.